# W10 RSAT Installation Issue

Tags: windows, dism, sysadmin

I am having issues installing Remote Server Administration Tools on my W10 Pro laptop. This is my attempts and issues so far:

1. Download `WindowsTH-RSAT_WS2016-x64.msu` from here: [Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows | Official Microsoft Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520)
2. Run
3. Installer finishes then reports a reboot is required.
4. Reboot
5. No programs were installed.
6. Run installer again
7. No reboot prompted installer finishes, still no software installed (looking for server manager in start)
8. Command prompt as admin

   ```
   C:\Windows\system32> expand -f:* c:\WindowsTH-RSAT_WS2016-x64.msu C:\RSAT
   C:\Windows\system32> dism.exe /online /add-package /packagepath:C:\RSAT\WindowsTH-KB2693643-x64.cab
   ```

   Prompt appears asking for a restart. I respond Y.
9. Reboot completes, still no software.

I am not sure where I can get more information on what is happening. I did go ahead and pull out the DISM log. I am not experienced in reading this log, not sure what is normal or abnormal. https://pastebin.com/CrQbDgj0

Answer (score 1):

The RSAT-Setup (MSU) just adds the tools to your windows image, but does not *install* them. You have to activate them by yourself ("Activate Windows-Features", just type 'Feature' into the Start Menu).

You can use the commandline, too:
`dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:feature name`

For exmple, add ActiveDirectory tools:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-DS
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-DS-SnapIns
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Features
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Features-GP
```

you can also get the whole list with:

```
dism /online /get-features | more
```

Comment: I am getting a feature name not recognized error. I reran the installer and tried to add again same result.

Comment: ... when you are doing ...what?

Comment: Sorry poorly written comment, if I run these dism commands that you posted above such as "dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:RemoteServerAdministrationTools" I am getting Feature Name not recognized.